# Is it possible to do clipping/mask in blender similar to clipping in drawing programs?

Tags: materials, camera, masking

In, for example, Photoshop, you can make a certain layer be visible only where there is a selected mask layer underneath it.
I'm trying to style my 3D model in Blender for 2D. How can you achieve the same mask effect, so that object is only visible if there is a chosen object behind it (from camera's perspective)?

Comment: Could you add pictures to illustrate what you are looking for ? Is the "behind" object completely hidden by the "front" object when looking through the camera view ? Are Geometry Nodes an option ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a material shader. You can probably also do it with a Boolean modifier depending on your needs.

For the shader setup, you need to mix a *Transparent BSDF* with the current shader your object uses (a *Principled BSDF* in the screenshot below). You can use the remapped distance with the other object as a mixing factor, but there are many other options.

[image: Mixing result]

This is how the object looks like without the mixing.

[image: Before mixing]

In this setup, you can freely move the Empty object to influence which part of the object is visible. You can use multiple Empty objects, and use the maximum of their remapped distances as the factor to show multiple parts of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Grease Pencil

[image]